# How to strip wire using Wire Wrapping Tool from OK Industries

Tags: connector, soldering, wire, tools

For learning wire wrapping, I have a [wire wrapping/unwrapping tool from OK Industries (HW-UW-3C)](http://www.jonard.com/jonard-ecommerce/control/product/~category_id=HAND_WRAP_TOOLS_1/~pcategory=OK_WIRE_WRAP_TOOLS/~product_id=10020;jsessionid=FB0FA8EB2AD8820069C4ACFE6AD224CA.jvm1#) and some 30 AWG wire wrapping wire.

Is it possible to use this tool to strip the wire?

[image]

Comment: Ignacio's answer is correct, I noticed the product video shows a couple of recommended strippers, although for occasional use you can also get normal wire strippers that go down to 30 AWG.

Answer (score 7):

Although some wirewrap tools include a wire stripper, either hidden away in the end of the handle or integrated into the middle of the handle itself, this one has neither. The two ends are for wrapping and unwrapping only, and you will require a separate stripper.